# Is there a way to enforce reject_if for accep accepts_nested_attributes_for only on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have something like

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions,  :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda {|q| q[:body].blank?}
```

The problem is that if I want to update questions and they are empty they are rejected which means they won't be validated.

Is there a way to enforce that the reject only happens on create and not update?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a check whether the `:id` value is blank? If it's blank then you know that it is a create.